# jquery break out date values from form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

We are working on a calendar project, where date values are stored/created in a form input.  I am trying to figure out how to use the date value from the input and break it apart to create a more graphical display date.  In the sample below, the date value from the 'arrival' input is to be displayed in the 'leftdate' span, departure in rightdate.

```
<li class="trip">
<span class="leftdate">17<br /><span class="smldate">OCT 11</span></span>
<span class="rightdate">23<br /><span class="smldate">OCT 11</span></span>
<span class="detail"><span class="stuff">other calendar functions</span>
<span class="date"> arr: <input class="arrival" value="17 Oct 11" /> - dep: <input class="departure" value="23 Oct 11" /></span>
</span>
</li>
```

The input value can be changed by the Date Picker, as well as by other JQuery scripts.  What I am needing is how to extract the value from the input after the change and then change the values in the leftdate and rightdate spans.

Comment: In which element the user gives input?

Comment: The initial date is manually set from a database when the <li> is originally created.  Subsequent changes are done manually by the user using JQuery UI datepicker or through javascript/jquery initiated changes in sibling LI (ie: change a date in one LI and all subsequent LIs have their dates updated (JQuery script)).

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript Date object.

Pass the value from the input that's collecting the date input from the user, and parse it like so:

```
var timestamp = Date.parse('nov 23 2011'); //returns ms since unix epoch
var dateObj = new Date(timestamp); //Creates a new date object from the timestamp

dateObj; //Returns "Wed Nov 23 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"

dateObj.getDate(); //Returns "23"
dateObj.getMonth(); //Returns "10" (january is 0)
dateObj.getFullYear(); //Returns "2011"
```

[More about the javascript date object here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Then just set up an event listener on change for the datepicker, and have it update the appropriate elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are asking for. Change your code as shown below

```
<li class="trip">
<span class="leftdate" id="leftDate">17<br /><span class="smldate" id="leftsmldate">OCT 11</span></span>
<span class="rightdate" id="rightDate">23<br /><span class="smldate" id="rightsmldate">OCT 11</span></span>
<span class="detail"><span class="stuff">other calendar functions</span>
<span class="date"> arr: <input class="arrival" id="arrival" value="17 Oct 11" onchange="updateSpan(1,this)"/> - dep: <input class="departure" id="departure" value="23 Oct 11" onchange="updateSpan(2,this)" /></span>
</span>
</li>
function updateSpan(flag,obj)
{
    var val = obj.value;
    if(flag == 1)
    {
       document.getElementById("leftDate").innerHTML = val.split(" ")[0] + "</br>";
       document.getElementById("leftsmlate").innerHTML = val.split(" ")[1] + val.split(" ")[2];
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("rightDate").innerHTML = val.split(" ")[0] + "</br>";
       document.getElementById("rightsmlDate").innerHTML = val.split(" ")[1] + val.split(" ")[2];
    }

}
```

Hope this solves your problem.